# Error using NavigationView on version 23.1.0, Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-navigationview

Every time I try to use NavigationView widget as my drawer, gradle raises this message: `Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined`. The fact here is, there is no place where I have defined or overridden that attribute in my project, it doesn't exist, so why do I get this error message?. I'm 99% sure this issue is due to a conflict among support libraries. If someone has any idea how to get rid this error, please.

Here is my dependency configuration

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
```

Here is the error message

```
Error:(2) Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined
```

Comment: why don't you use libraries of one version 23.1.0?